# Почему этот код работает, несмотря на эффект type erasure?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Известно, что во время рантайма конкретный дженерик-тип неизвестен, т.к. стирается (type erasure), из-за этого даже в, к примеру в Scala, приспособлены отдельные костыли.

Однако, вот Java-код, возвращающий информацию о том, что в списке содержатся не какие-то элементы, а именно строки. Объясните, в чем подвох?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("one", "two");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field field = Main.class.getField("stringList");

        Type genericFieldType = field.getGenericType();

        if (genericFieldType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType aType = (ParameterizedType) genericFieldType;
            Type[] fieldArgTypes = aType.getActualTypeArguments();
            for (Type fieldArgType : fieldArgTypes) {
                Class fieldArgClass = (Class) fieldArgType;
                System.out.println("fieldArgClass = " + fieldArgClass);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: >>Известно, что во время рантайма<< А где это такое известно? Вам вообще о чём нибудь говорит слово "Метаданные"?

Comment: [_If the Type is a parameterized type, the Type object returned must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source code._](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType())

Comment: @test123 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java

Comment: Ответ в названии пакета, из которого вы импортируете класс `Field`, который, в свою очередь, предоставляет вам информацию о типах. Рефлексия - это такой чёрный ход, через который можно узнать и сделать многое, что в норме не должно быть доступно.

Comment: Тогда почему скаловский паттерн-матчинг не пользуется под капотом рефлексией для выяснения, какой конкретно дженерик рассматривается в кейсе? А вместо этого используются костыли?

Comment: хотелось бы пошутить, что Scal'овцы простаки, но не буду))

Comment: Кстати в топике, который вы указали есть два комментария. Вроде это относится к делу...как раз самый первый https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java#comment1881506_313590 и второй https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313584/what-is-the-concept-of-erasure-in-generics-in-java#comment1882753_313590 (the *objects* won't have different generic types. The *fields* know the types, but the *objects* don't.)

Comment: @TheSN во-первых потому, что рефлексия чертовски медленная. Во-вторых, лучше не пользоваться чёрными ходами без крайней необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!